# How can I improve the performance of a WordPress WooCommerce website that gets a low speed score from Google PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce

How can I make my WordPress WooCommerce website performance fast?

My website is http://www.furniturehub.pk/. But it is loading too slow.

I have also checked its performance using Google PageSpeed Insights and it scores 64/100. So how can I make it FASTER?

Comment: Try a different theme. Be careful with themes from themeforest, rockettheme etc. Their authors often stuff tons of CSS and javascript just to attract customers, but this slows down the site so much it's unusable in production

Comment: But now i have used this for production purpose. Do you have any solution to make it better and faster?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it as about website performance and would be better asked at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

1. 18 css and 37 js separate files load,
2. no caching headers
3. 1 of 18 css files size 1 MB

you have many problems here. Google PageSpeed Tools helps a lot with site optimization (it crashes checking your site for me)

http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

Your website has images that are 1200x300 when there really only using 300x70 space.
since your website is mainly pictures you should resize all of them to be smaller.